# IntelliSense getting in the way during plain text entry

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm entering plain text in a paragraph with the necessary line breaks for keeping a required line width <80,  I am very often tripped up with IntelliSense.

Seems like there should be some way to configure vscode to turn off IntelliSense when within an html p tag. Or is there some other better solution?

Comment: just learned about editor.rulers which helps mediate the situation somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't actually need to hardwarp, try using "editor.wrappingColumn" for configure add soft wrapping.

You may be seeing word based suggestions or snippet suggestions. To disable these, use the setting:

- `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false` - Disable any suggestions taken from words in the current document.
- `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"` - Disable snippet suggestions.

You can also apply these settings to only html files using

```
"[html]": {
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
}
```

Also take a look at the settings `"editor.quickSuggestions"` and `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter"` to control when suggestions are shown and how they are accepted.